# ContentsOfURL returns nil in swift 2.0 from a perfectly valid URL

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, nsdata

I am trying to fetch an image from a URL but the contentsOfURL method keeps returning nil. The url is legal and has only one image.
I have tried the dispatch_get_global_queue method and also the method described below. The NSData value is always nil no matter how many times i run. i have already tried restarting the simulator as well. The network is also fast and there are no issues with the network.
This is the part of the code that is failing

```
var imageURL : NSURL(string : "https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/wave_earth_mosaic_3.jpg")

if let url = imageURL{
        spinner?.startAnimating()
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){(data,response,error) -> Void in
            self.imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
        }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                if url == self.imageURL{
                    self.image = UIImage(data: self.imageData!)
                }
                else{

                }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: valid? really? take a close look ;)

Comment: sorry that got pasted wrongly! I am infact trying the correct url.

Comment: you are using  http and https both...you need to use any one of them...open that url in browser, you'll get an idea

Comment: I got that. Thank you . The error still persists

Comment: What does says the `error` in the closure? I don't understand why you do `contensOfURL:`, while you already have it (`data`) with the `NSURLSession`

Comment: i am getting an unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping the imageData!

Comment: using data directly also gave the same issue. So was trying with contentsOfUrl

Comment: NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed this is the error

Comment: Never force unwrap a variable - always use the `if let` syntax especially for remote resources. Also, edit your question to include the `NSURLSession` error.

Comment: This works for me in a playground - https://gist.github.com/paulw11/90834a063d8e5ac715b8ed064e00544e It is a big image though, so it takes a while to transfer

Comment: You're downloading the image data twice, with NSURLSession + NSData. This doesn't make much sense and should be fixed before worrying about other issues.

Comment: The code you posted makes no sense. Get rid of the `contentsOfURL` call and post your original code that you are having trouble with, along with the specific line that's crashing and the exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

This is how your function should look like. No need for GCD.
There is also no need for `let task = ....` and `NSData(contentsOfURL: url)` downloads the image again as **Eric D** stated.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var imageURL = "https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/wave_earth_mosaic_3.jpg"

        loadImage(fromUrl: imageURL) { (image, error) in
            if let image = image {
                print("got an image")
            } else {
                print("got an error")
            }
        }
    }

    // pretty function that takes a string and a callback
    // it sends either an image or an error back through the callback
    func loadImage(fromUrl urlString: String, completion:(image:UIImage?,error:NSError?) -> Void) {

        guard let url = NSURL(string:urlString) else {
            // invalid url
            completion(image: nil,error: nil)
            return
        }

        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) in

            if let error = error {
                completion(image: nil,error: error)
                return
            }

            guard let data = data, image = UIImage(data:data) else {
                // no connection error, but no image extracted from data
                return completion(image: nil, error: nil)
            }

            completion(image: image, error: nil)
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: `I also got an error on the Nasa link` Maybe the server wasn't too happy back then, but I got the image ok with OP's url a few minutes ago.

Comment: Also, err... why does OP *and you too* download with NSData inside a closure where the data is already being downloaded by NSURLSession? You're downloading the image data twice, this code doesn't make much sense to me. :)

Comment: @EricD Did not analyse that part of the code, but you are right, makes no sense.

Comment: Got rid of the contentsOfURL part. Now ican see that data is being returned. However it is not set to image view and giving blank screen. :(

Comment: @user2604897 did the print return "got an image"? if so, implement setting the image to a `UIImageView` at the position of `print("got an image")`